# Turtle and Pygame window instantly closing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgdDN.png) I'm a beginner and I'm coding in PyCharm (Python 3). I built a pong game using the turtle module and it worked fine. Today I wanted to built a football game similar like pong, but I'm trying to make the screen and it opens and instantly closes.. The same happened to me while i tried to use the pygame module. My code is correct, I changed the python interpreter from 3.6 to 3.8 still nothing. Can anyone pls help?

Comment: Please share your code snippet along with error stack trace(if any).

Comment: Share the code here and not a screenshot of the code in a link...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code executes correctly and once it reaches the end, the program exits. Add `input()` to the end of the code to halt it.

Comment: that works, when i run the code it opens up the window but then it says that it's not responding.

Answer (score -1):

```
import turtle   
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
```

I don't really know your problem but I think you need to initialize the turtle first.